# Element.find method not working in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Following is the implementation of my directive:

```
function Upload(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        template: '<input type="file" id="uploader" name="files[]" multiple /><button id="submit">submit</button>',
        controller: 'inputControl',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){
            console.log(elem);
            console.log(elem.find('input[type=\'file\']'));
            elem.find('#submit').bind('click', function() {
                console.log(elem.find('input[type=\'file\']'));
                elem.find('input[type=\'file\']').click();
            });
            elem.find('input[type=\'file\']').on('click', scope.fileSelectionHandler);
            scope.$on("$destroy",function Destructor(){
                elem.find('input[type=\'file\']').off('click', scope.fileSelectionHandler);
            });

        }
    }
}

app.directive('fUpload',['Data','$rootScope', Upload]);
```

**HTML Code**

```
 <f-upload></f-upload>
```

The template is rendering, scope is, well, applied, but elem.find method still returns an empty prototype and thus no watchers and listeners of the directive are called. I'm new to angular! Help would really be appreciated.

**EDIT**
I tried `$timeout` with delay of 0s. It didn't work.

Comment: Debug it, as I recall the inner elements aren’t present at time the ‘link‘ function is called.

Comment: How can I access the inner elements? Also, isn't link function similar to the post-compile method of a directive. Shouldn't the elements be loaded already by the time 'link' function is called? Correct me if I'm wrong. :)

Comment: Also, I ^can^ access elem.children(). That most certainly means that inner elements are loaded, no?

Comment: It would sem so, try it with debugger then copy the working code...